# Why is my UIButton not where I think it should be?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIView `self.addProjectContainer` that has a frame of (0 198; 300 30).  I'm creating a UIButton and adding it as a subview of that UIView programmatically.  This is the property that holds a reference to the button:

```
var addProjectButton:UIButton?
```

and this is what I do in the ViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
self.addProjectButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
self.addProjectButton!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.addProjectButton!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Redraw
self.addProjectButton!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 30)
self.addProjectButton!.setTitle("+ Add Project", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.addProjectContainer.addSubview(self.addProjectButton!)
```

The containing UIView is positioned correctly, which I verified by giving it a background color and also using the debugger:

```
(lldb) po self.addProjectContainer
<UIView: 0x7fa43c019a40; frame = (0 198; 300 30); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa43c019bb0>>
```

My problem is that the button isn't showing up in that view, and here's what the debugger tells me:

```
(lldb) po self.addProjectButton
▿ Optional<UIButton>
  - Some : <UIButton: 0x7fa43ac596a0; frame = (-10 -309; 94 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa43ac58dd0>>
```

If I change the button to a label:

```
var addProjectLabel:UILabel?
```

and add it to the view like so:

```
let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 220, height: 30)
self.addProjectLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
self.addProjectLabel!.text = "+ Add Project"
self.addProjectContainer.addSubview(self.addProjectLabel!)
```

the label shows up exactly where I want the button to appear:

```
(lldb) po self.addProjectLabel
▿ Optional<UILabel>
  - Some : <UILabel: 0x7fc560d2d2a0; frame = (0 0; 220 30); text = '+ Add Project'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fc560d40a00>>
```

How can I get the button to show up in the right place, as the label does?  This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut the line about `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. It causes your `frame` to be ignored.

Or, if you are going to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, position using constraints, not `frame`.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know that about translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.  My button is where I expected it to be now.